# Get application liker via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get all the facebook user id whose like my application via a graph api.
Please give any suggestion.

Like facebook fan page showing application liker randomly. I also want to access my application liker list and want to save in database.

Please tell me if any possibility? Need your suggestion...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think that's possible for privacy reasons Facebook doesn't allow it. You need to get people who like you application to install and authenticate it before you can find out more about them. However, I do remember someone managing to scrape the fans of a page before so maybe that's possible for applications as well...

Comment: But the same thing is with fanbox. Facebook fanbox show all facebook member randomly whose like your application, then why facebook not give user detail who like my application via api.